# temporarily suppress hyphenation

Tags: hyphenation

On the title page of an article I want to insert a paragraph containing keywords. For indexing purposes (e. g. web search engines), I'd like to have the keywords unhyphenated (temporarily, of course). At the same time, the paragraph should be flushed at both sides, even though inter-word spaces may become larger than usual.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: `\begin{hyphenrules}{nohyphenation}Text\end{hyphenrules}`, if you're using `babel`.

Comment: @egreg: Could you please turn this into an answer?

Comment: @egreg: Placing `\begin{sloppypar}` and `\end{sloppypar}` around the non-hyphenated paragraph seems to be necessary, as Herbert and David pointed out.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

it makes sense to put the text into `\begin{sloppypar}...\end{sloppypar}` when it is not hyphenated.

```
\listfiles
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\textwidth=10cm
\begin{document}
\blindtext

\foreignlanguage{nohyphenation}{\begin{sloppypar}\blindtext\end{sloppypar}}

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried `\foreignlanguage{nohyphenation}{\sloppy\blindtext}`. While hyphenation is disabled, there is no justification at the margins.

Comment: yes, see my edit

Comment: Thanks! `\begin{sloppypar}\foreignlanguage{nohyphenation}{\blindtext}\end{sloppypar}` works.

Comment: Actually for me the `\begin...\end ` didn't have any effect, the `\foreignlanguage{...} ` on its own is sufficient.

Answer (score 21):

Hyphenation can be disabled in different ways. One is to set

```
\hyphenpenalty=10000
\exhyphenpenalty=10000
```

that assign "infinite" cost to discretionary and explicit hyphens respectively.

Another way is to choose a language with no hyphenation patterns, which is more efficient, because it spares TeX from computing demerits.

All modern TeX distributions have already such a language in their predefined set, and it's called `nohyphenation`. If you're using `babel`, then

```
\begin{hyphenrules}{nohyphenation}
<text>
\end{hyphenrules}
```

will allow line breaking only at explicit hyphens. If you want to disable also them, then setting `\exhyphenpenalty=10000` is still necessary. However, one has to cope with paragraph setting, allowing larger interword spaces without too many `Underfull \hbox` messages, which is obtained by saying `\sloppy`.

A "complete" solution might be to define a `nohyphens` environment so that one can type

```
\begin{nohyphens}
Text not to be hyphenated
\end{nohyphens}
```

in the following way

```
\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{babel}
  {\newenvironment{nohyphens}
     {\par\sloppy\exhyphenpenalty=\@M
      \@ifundefined{l@nohyphenation}
        {\language=\@cclv}
        {\hyphenrules{nohyphenation}}%
     }
     {\par
      \@ifundefined{l@nohyphenation}
        {}
        {\endhyphenrules}%
     }
  }
  {\newenvironment{nohyphens}
     {\par\sloppy\exhyphenpenalty=\@M
      \@ifundefined{l@nohyphenation}
        {\language=\@cclv}
        {\language=\l@nohyphenation}%
     }
     {\par}
  }
\makeatother
```

If `babel` is loaded we use its features, otherwise we simply set the current language to the "no hyphenation" one, if existent; in the worst case we set the language number to 255, which *shouldn't* be defined (TeX formats usually assign progressive numbers to the enabled languages and having 256 of them is highly unlikely).

Note that assigning `\language=-1` is not a solution: the TeXbook says, at p. 455,

> If `\language` is negative or greater than 255, TeX acts as if `\language = 0`

Answer (score 13):

You can make hyphens infinitely expensive

```
  \hyphenpenalty=10000
```

or use a language without any hyphenation patterns loaded

```
  \newlanguage\nohy
  \language=\nohy
```

Then you might want to use `\sloppy` or `\begin{sloppypar}...\end{sloppypar}` so the word spacing can stretch more than usual.

Comment: Thank you very much for this explanation! I'd prefer @egreg 's approach, though. It is more LaTeX-style.

Comment: Yes but it requires having read the babel manual which is cheating I'm sure:-)  Note you may still want to use sloppy(par) to handle white space, the babel declaration just turns off hyphenation I think.

Comment: afaict from experimenting with `hyphenrules`, the paragraph is flushed to both sides. This implies larger inter-word space I guess, right?

Comment: Yes it doesn't change the justification but without relaxing the normal rules so TeX may have to stretch space too much or it may stick text into the margin (both of these are infinitely bad) `\sloppy` tells tex that stretching white space isn't _so_ bad so it will do that in preference to having over-full boxes (and it will not complain about boxes being underfull due to over-stretched space)

Comment: …and then `\selectlanguage{english}` when ready to resume hyphenation.

Answer (score 0):

Individual words can be excluded from hyphenation by using [the \mbox{} command](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Text_Formatting). This also works for dates or multiple words.
For instance:

```
The following word will not hyphenate: \mbox{keywordnottohyphenate}. Neither will the following date: \mbox{2020-08-23}
```

\mbox is a standard LaTeX command, so should work without any packages to include in your preamble.